# GAMS data entry

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gams-math

I am trying to include the following to GAMS:

- Parameter data(a1,a2,'f') -> This is supposed to be a look-up table, the combination of a value for a1 and a2 always lead to the same f value.
- a1 and a2 are different for each node (indexed v) -> For each node v I have a different value for a1 and a2 which will be defined in the equations.

My question is, which data type should a1 and a2 be? A set a1(v) does not work because each v can just have one value a1 then. But to be an index in parameter data(a1,a2,'f'), it must be a set, right?

Is there any modeling trick to overcome this?